# How to check if any active Stream has already been listened to?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

Is there any way to check if there is any active Stream that has already been listened to or not in Dart/Flutter?

Suppose there is a Stream that has been listened to on one Screen. But, I need to listen to that Stream on another screen. So that I need to check if there is any active stream that has been already listened to or not.

Comment: you can declare a boolean and if stream is being listened to, make it true. then pass it to the other screens to check this.

Answer (score 8):

You've to use `StreamController` in order to check if the stream's been listened to already by using `StreamController`'s handy `hasListener` getter.

Here's minimal sample code to understand:

```
StreamController controller = StreamController();
controller.addStream(getNumbersAsStream());

controller.stream.listen((e) => print(e));
if (!controller.hasListener) {
  controller.stream.listen((e) => print(e));
} else {
  print("Stream has already been listened");
}
```